# Not able to install mod_perl module on the server

Tags: apache, perl, mod-perl

In my site I am getting an error : `an error occurred while processing this directive`
It was working fine before moving to the new server. So when I checked I found that mod_perl module is missing. So I tried to install it by downloading the module to the server and then tried to run using `Perl Makefile.pl` but it was asking for apache src and I was not able to find it. I can see `/usr/bin/apache/` folder but no source file inside the folder.
So I tried to install the module from Cpanel but I got the following error:

```
The C compiler is not functional and auto repair failed. Perl module installs require a working C compiler. Please repair the C compiler and try again.
```

Please let me know how to install it as I have tried most of the cases searching the net.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It's probably best to use your distro's packaging system to install mod_perl, especially, if apache is installed from a package too.

Yum based systems:

```
yum install mod_perl
```

Deb based systems

```
apt-get install mod_perl
```

you may need to enable the module using a2enmod

Comment: I got the error when I tried the code: $ apt-get install mod_perl
-bash: apt-get: command not found
$ yum install mod_perl
-bash: yum: command not found

Comment: Hmm, then the either the server uses some other packaging system, or those tools have been removed. Is there any way you can find out which distro is used? Can you ask your server admin/hosting company?

Comment: CLOUDLINUX 6.7 x86_64 standard is used

Comment: CloudLinux is based on RHEL and uses "yum". It's possible that "yum" just isn't in your path when running as a normal user. You're supposed to run "yum" as the supersuser.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly gcc is either corrupted or not present on your system. Please try to re/install gcc on your system

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

On Redhat:

```
yum update
yum install devtoolset-2-toolchain
```

Comment: I am not sure of the server , whether its redhat anything else but when I tried the code and got the error: $ sudo apt-get update
-bash: sudo: command not found
$ yum update
-bash: yum: command not found

Comment: Ok, could you please post the results of the following command from your system:
uname -a

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a problem with your installation of `gcc`. You're using CloudLinux, so you should use `yum` to reinstall `gcc`.

```
$ sudo -i yum install gcc
```

But you don't need `gcc` if you install the pre-build packages.

```
$ sudo -i yum install mod_perl
```

Either way, you're going to need to get to grips with package installation for your system - and for that you're going to need root access.